# Select and Input next to each other

Tags: css

I'm trying to put a select tag and input tag next to each other, similar to how Amazon has their search bar configured.

My issue is I'd like to have the search bar scale by browser width, without collapsing onto the next line even when the window is small.

How could that be achieved? Below is my attempt...

```
**HTML**

<div class="container">
  <select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something...">
</div>

**CSS**

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  width: 4%;
}

input {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, this should work.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}


input {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, No problem :)